# How to stop ffmpeg increasing image size when adding watermark

Tags: image, ffmpeg, watermark

I'm trying to add a border over many images by overlaying the border as a watermark.

My input image is 5.13x7.63 inches but the output is 16.03x23.84 inches. How do I prevent this and get output as the same size as input?

The command I'm using is:

```
ffmpeg -i input.png -vf "movie=border.png [watermark]; [in][watermark] overlay=0:0 [out]" output.png
```

where input.png and border.png are the same dimensions and in the same folder.

I was expecting the output to be the same size as input.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently ffmpeg cant control the dpi of an image. When adding borders, it takes my 300dpi image and turns it into a 72dpi one but with larger dimensions. You can use photoshop to resize to the original dpi and dimensions. Use actions to automate and batch process it if you have a lot of images